# Insertar un icono/img dentro de la etiqueta <select> <option> en HTML

Tags: html5, html-select

En **google Contacts**, al momento de seleccionar un pais, te muestra una lista de opciones con sus imagenes así:

[image: imagen d google contacts]

Al tratar de imitarlo con la etiqueta **select** y **option** simplemente no me muestra las imagenes pero si el texto

```
 <select class="form-select" name="owner" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option   value="1"><img src="../icon/google/youtube.svg" height="20"> valor 1</option>
      <option   value="2"><img src="../icon/google/youtube.svg" height="20"> valor 2</option>
      <option   value="3"><img src="../icon/google/youtube.svg" height="20"> valor 3</option>
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al colocar la imagen fuera de las etiquetas **select** y **option**, si me muestra la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces
**¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo, quizas con otra etiqueta?**

Comment: Tu código debe ir como texto por favor

Comment: Tal vez te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361942/mostrar-imagenes-en-select/361963#361963)

Comment: Simplemente puedes usar emojis para las banderas, como se explica [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737763/5587982). Otra alternativa interesante sería FontAwesome,  en el enlace hay también una respuesta que explica cómo hacerlo.