# Insertar banderas en <option> para una landing web

Tags: html, css, select

Mi pregunta es sencilla. Tengo que insertar distintas banderas dentro de un option:select

```
 <select><option><img src="bandera"></option></select>
```

Mi problema es que es una landing de posicionamiento:

Al ser una landing, no puedo insertar ninguna librería Javascript, por lo que Jquery y Boostrap quedan descartados. Las librerías suelen dar dolores de cabeza para un performance 100%.

No puedo insertar emojis, ya que los he probado y no funcionan en muchos navegadores y en sistemas operativos. Nuestros clientes potenciales son usuarios no adaptados a nuevas tecnologías, principalmente, y muchos de ellos utilizan Windows XP.

He encontrado una solución para windows con los emojis, pero los usuarios window no los verán.

```
 if (/windows/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   function flagemojiToPNG(){
     return ""
   }
   var reg = new RegExp('(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}', 'g');
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll(reg, flagemojiToPNG());

  }
```

De todas maneras, lo ideal para mi sería insertar las banderas en .svg mediante CSS dentro de la etiqueta option, pero no doy con la clave.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mostrar imagenes en select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361942/mostrar-imagenes-en-select)

Comment: Ya lo había visto antes, desgraciadamente no me sirve ninguna de las respuestas para una landing de posicionamiento.   De todas maneras he hecho una solución con los emojis, cuando sea edge, pues no se verá las banderas.

Comment: Pero puedes usar Javascript vanilla?

Comment: Si, como he puesto en la pregunta, utilizo un pequeño código para no mostrar las banderas si es window (Que tengo que modificarlo para que reconozca si es menor que windows 9). Ya que los sistemas operativos anteriores no reconocen emojis.

Answer (score 2):

Si no te parece una opción muy extrema podrías hacer un dropdown personalizado con html, css y javascript vanilla.
De esta manera tendrías control absoluto sobre el dropdown y sus estilos, algo asi:

```js
(function() {
  // código básico para imitar un select por defecto:
  function getClosestMatch(target, className) {
    return target.classList.contains(className) ?
       target :
       target.closest('.' + className);
  }

  function getDropdown(target, bypass) {
     if (target.className.startsWith('dropdown-') && !bypass) return;
     return getClosestMatch(target, 'dropdown');
  }
  
  function getDropdownOption(target) {
     return getClosestMatch(target, 'dropdown-option');
  }
  
  function handlePopup(dropdown, close) {
    var popup = dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-options');
    if (popup) {
        if (close) popup.classList.remove('open');
        else popup.classList.toggle('open');
    }
  }
  
  function toggle(dropdown) {
    if (dropdown) handlePopup(dropdown, false);
    else document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')
           .forEach(function (item) {
             handlePopup(item, true);
           });
  }
  
  function handleDropdownClick(e) {
    var dropdown = getDropdown(e.target);
    if (dropdown) toggle(dropdown);
    else toggle();
  }
  
  function handleOptionClick(e) {
    var option = getDropdownOption(e.target);

    if (option) {
      var dropdown = getDropdown(option, true);
      dropdown.querySelector('input').value = option.dataset.value;
      dropdown.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-option').forEach(function(op) {
        op.classList.remove('selected');
      });
      option.classList.add('selected');
    }
  }
  
  // con esta función muestras las imágenes de las banderas:
  function displayOptionFlags() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-option')
      .forEach(function(option) {
        var flag = option.dataset.flag;
        if (flag) {
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = flag;
          img.width = 16;
          img.height = 12;
          option.appendChild(img);
        }
      });
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handleDropdownClick(e);
    handleOptionClick(e);
  });
  
  displayOptionFlags();
})();
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

.dropdown::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' %3F%3E%3Csvg height='1792' viewBox='0 0 1792 1792' width='1792' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M1395 736q0 13-10 23l-466 466q-10 10-23 10t-23-10l-466-466q-10-10-10-23t10-23l50-50q10-10 23-10t23 10l393 393 393-393q10-10 23-10t23 10l50 50q10 10 10 23z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown > input {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px solid rgb(118, 118, 118);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  line-height: 18px;
  width: auto;
}

.dropdown-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(238,232,231);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(238,232,231,1) 0%, rgba(242,237,236,1) 51%, rgba(238,232,231,1) 100%);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: .3rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}

.dropdown-options.open {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-option {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: .2rem .8rem;
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-option img {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-option.selected::before {
  content: '\2713';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 3px;
}

.dropdown-option:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-option:active {
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" size='15' value="Select" readonly />
  <div class="dropdown-options">
    <div class="dropdown-option selected" data-value="Select">
      Select
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-option"
         data-value="Spanish"
         data-flag="https://flagcdn.com/16x12/es.png">
      Spanish
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-option"
         data-value="English"
         data-flag="https://flagcdn.com/16x12/gb-eng.png">
      English
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes usar este snippet y modificarlo a tu antojo hasta que obtengas el resultado visual que quieres. El límite aquí es tu imaginación realmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo pruebo y pongo feedback.